# mongoDB, connection refused

Tags: java, mongodb

Show my code

```
conf.set( "mongo.input.uri" , "mongodb://127.0.0.1/stackoverflow.mrtest" );
conf.set( "mongo.output.uri" , "mongodb://127.0.0.1/stackoverflow.mrtest_out2" );
```

the code runs without error when the host is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. But when the host changed to my ip wlan0 `192.168.1.102`, it returned the following error

```
Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.1.102:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.1.102:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

I have open the port 27017.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -ptcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

How should I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Your Firewall is intercepting it maybe? Or mangodb is only binded to the loopback interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default MongoDB only binds to the loopback interface which makes it only accessible from localhost. To change that you need to edit this line in `mongod.conf` file;

```
# /etc/mongod.conf

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

you can change it to `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,192.168.1.102` to allow LAN and local connections or you can remove or comment out that line to allow all connections.

For more info : [MongoDB – Allow remote access](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/)

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons of it , which in short can be concluded as **Your Application is unable to Communicate  mongoDB service**

1.Check your MongoDB using the same IP configured in your application.yml file,
If not then configure the same used by MongoDB:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
---
  spring:
    profiles: dev
    data:
      mongodb:
        host: localhost
        port: 27017
```

Here i assumed my mongo running on localhost, and port 27017, so i configured accordingly.

2. Check whether your MongoDB service up and running , How to check ?
   Execute following command in your terminal

> sudo service mongodb status

```
   <pre><code>
    ● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-07-03 20:10:15 IST; 1min 54s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Main PID: 14305 (mongod)
    Tasks: 23 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─14305 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf</pre></code>
```

If Status not visible as active and running, you need to start/restart the service

> sudo service mongodb restart

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine that it was an issue with the bind parameter in the /etc/mongod.conf.  Instead of commenting it out I set it to 0.0.0.0 to all for remote access.

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception: **com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket**

Solution:

Verify whether you have started **"mongo daemon"** or not.

Windows Terminal: **mongod.exe**

Linux Termina: **mongod**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Spring Boot** and are following the [Quick Start](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/quick-start/), make sure you put this configuration in your `application.properties`

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=[YOUR_URI]
```